# Keep format time in array (VBA Excel)

Tags: arrays, excel, time, format, vba

I put several data (Names, dates, times and values) into an array. It goes wrong with the date and time.
Where do I go wrong? Here is a piece of my code:

```
    For i = 1 To LastRow + 13
    For j = 1 To 10
    strArray(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value2
    Next j
 Next i
```

So 0,000983796 should become 0:01:25.

Comment: `Value2` returns a Double. Use `Value` instead.

Comment: Doesn't work. It keeps the value 0,000983796 in the array.

Comment: You should use a `variant` array or a `type` array. And how areyu dimensioning your array?

Comment: Dim strArray As Variant

Answer (score 2):

> In Excel, a date is the number of days since January 1, 1900 starting
>   with January 1, 1900 being “1”. Each date after that, Excel adds one
>   more number to that sequence. So August 26, 2013 is 41512, or 41,512
>   days since January 1, 1900.
>
> The integer part of the number is used for the days. The decimal part
>   of the number is the fractional part of the day — or the time. So .5
>   would be 50% of the way thru the day, or 12:00 noon. That makes
>   41,512.5 to be equivalent to 12:00 noon on August 26, 2013.

From [DATE VALUES IN EXCEL EXPLAINED](http://officepowerups.com/2013/08/26/date-values-in-excel/)

You can convert this number value back into something more pretty and readable.

```
dim pretty as String
pretty = Format(Cells(i, j).Value2, "h:mm:ss")
```

[More examples on vba formatting](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-format-date/)

Comment: I knew about your first part. But thank you for the example. It just works perfectly! I had something done like that kind of format for another part of the program, but I have forgotten that it could work for this.

Comment: @Helfenstein glad to hear it worked. Please flag it as solved if you don't need any more help :)